# Where do I post a question about a JRE/JDK problem?

Tags: discussion

I need help enabling my JVM in IE. I have tried everything out there. Where do I ask for help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com)

From the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> - computer hardware,
> - **computer software**, or
> - personal and home computer networking

*(emphasis mine)*

Possibly relevant tags:

- [java](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/java)
- [jdk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/jdk)
- [jre](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/jre)
- [jvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/jvm)

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you so much